# How to connect solr with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, solr

I followed https://github.com/gsf/node-solr,installed node-solr with

```
npm install solr
```

then how to connect solr in 8080 port?

Answer (score 6):

you can use solr-node npm packege it's really simple to configure. here is working example of calling solr from nodesjs and fetching data from solr

```
 var SolrNode = require('solr-node');
    var client = new SolrNode({
        host: '<your host>',
        port: '8983',
        core: 'products',
        protocol: 'http'
    });
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
app.get('/getProduct',
 function (req, res) 
 { 
var strQuery = client.query().q('productId:9788700075740');
 client.search(strQuery, function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
   }
   console.log('Response:', result.response);
   res.send(result.response);
});
 }); 
 app.listen(3000, 
 function () { 
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!') });
```

you can explore solr-node on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node

Comment: `npm install solr-client` stopped at bignumber.js fetching, I am already known how to connect solr with node-solr,thanks anyway,I will post my answer immedialy

Comment: @XieWilliam it's solr-node code not solr-client if you want to use it use npm install solr-node to install

Comment: Just to note that `solr-node` now looks quite unloved and has significant security vulnerabilities. `solr-client` it probably a better option now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var solr = require('solr')
var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '8080',
    core: 'bt', // if defined, should begin with a slash
    path: '/solr/' // should also begin with a slash
};
// Create a client
var solrClient = solr.createClient(options);
```

put this options in the solr.createClient solved my question

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Solr-client for node js.

```
npm install --save solr-client

// Load dependency
var solr = require('solr-client');

// Create a client
var client = solr.createClient();

// Add a new document
client.add({ id : 12, title_t : 'Hello' },function(err,obj){
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
      console.log('Solr response:', obj);
   }
});
```